# When, where to load php library in order to extend the included class?

Tags: php, class, oop, drupal-7, libraries

*NB: When i'm talking about "libraries" i'm refering to [Libraries API](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries) module, version 7.x-2.x.*

#### Scenario:

- 3rd-party PHP library defines a class: "BaseClass", in BaseClass.php
- Drupal module BaseClassExtender.module implements hook_libraries_info() to expose the lib
- BaseClassExtender.info declares files[] = BaseClassExtender.php
- file BaseClassExtender.php defines class BaseClassExtender extends BaseClass

#### Problem:

Drupal throws a fatal error because BaseClassExtender.php is included before BaseClass.php

#### Question:

How, when do I call libraries_load() (or should i be calling something else?) so that the BaseClass gets included first?

Comment: Please include your code. Where exactly is the problem occuring?

Comment: The problem i'm seeing is because the 3rd-party lib is needed during the process of loading menu args. In my specific case, i'm using hook_user_load on a user/$uid path. My solution is to add an addition libraries_load() function inside my hook_user_load(), but it's no redundant to where i'm loading in hook_init()

Comment: Please copy your code into your question so we can see it.